# ¿Como pasar los datos obtenidos por getUserMedia a un Stream binario?

Tags: javascript, websocket

Quiero saber como obtener la información de un MediaStream en forma de cadena binaria para posteriormente poder enviarla mediante WebSocket a un servidor.

Por lo que se, la información se almacena en forma de Blob dentro de la memoria y lo único que pude obtener hasta ahora es una URL que da hacia esa información.

Crea que hay posibilidades utilizando etiquetas HTML vídeo y canvas. Pero me parece una perdida de recursos innecesaria crear elementos de visualización que no quiero, ya que mi único objetivo es enviar los datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando un `MediaRecorder` recibe datos en el stream, se dispara un `BlobEvent` el cual tiene los datos recibidos como `Blob`:

```
recorder.ondatavailable = e => data.push(e.data);
```

Que luego puedes unir para crear un `Blob` que es la recreación del recurso enviado por stream:

```
let video = new Blob(data, { type: 'video/webm' });
```

> Quiero saber como obtener la información de un MediaStream en forma de **cadena binaria** para posteriormente poder enviarla mediante WebSocket a un servidor.

De hecho, si te fijas en las firmas de la función [`Websocket#send`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#send()), esta está sobrecargada para soportar tres tipos de datos:

- `DOMString` (es un simple string UTF-16)
- [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/ArrayBuffer)
- [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Blob)

> Vale, eso ya lo sé, pero necesito que se envía en forma binaria.

En ese caso, podrías usar el método [`FileReader#readAsArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer) para convertir el blob a buffer binario:

```
let raw; // contenido binario
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = buffer => raw = buffer;
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(video);
```